# TV series about two partners who had a time-travelling pocket watch, went back and met Edison

Tags: story-identification

In the 1980/90s there was a TV show airing in the Eastern USA about two partners who had this pocket watch that was actually a time machine.

I distinctly remember an episode where the two time traveled to Thomas Edison's time and met him. Mr. Edison pick pocketed the watch and completely disassembled it to *see how it worked*. Panic ensued till he was able to reassemble it. Apparently in the the process it taught Mr. Edison how a light filament works and was the catalyst for him inventing the light bulb.

Anyone know what this series was called?

Comment: I recall pretty much every episode I saw there was some panic ensuing revolving around the watch falling into the wrong hands...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks the miracle of <strike>Google</strike> Yahoo the show in question is called ["Voyagers!" (1982)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083500/combined).

Screen Shot:
[image]